# WooCommerce Layered Filter (Location > Product Type)

Tags: wordpress, filter, woocommerce, product, taxonomy

I want my homepage to have a drop-down menu of locations. After the user selected the location, they will be directed to the shop based on their selected location (products from other locations will not be shown). Then they can apply the product filters like colours and all.

I've created a new taxonomy (Locations) and products are categorized into their respective locations.

So how am I going to make this layered filter to work, because usually those plugins I've found online are not built for this?